# pattern and matcher in Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java. i searched the google and could not get any thing. please help me.
I want this out put from my sentences.

> 1-Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon
>   2-2
>   3-18

I cannot write proper `resultRegexString`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String currentString = "Title:Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon,Quantity: 2, Price: $18";
        String resultRegexString = "Title\\: ([^,]+), Quantity\\: ([^,]+), Price\\: \\$([\\W\\w]+)";
        Pattern resultRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(resultRegexString);
        Matcher resultRegexMatcher = resultRegexPattern.matcher(currentString);
        if(resultRegexMatcher.find()){
             System.out.println(resultRegexMatcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(resultRegexMatcher.group(2));
            System.out.println(resultRegexMatcher.group(3));
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can there be commas in the keys? What about colons? Are the escaped somehow if they are?

Comment: Please be slightly more descriptive about your problem.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, no commas and no colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's a formatting issue. Either remove spaces on regexp or add spaces in input string.

```
String currentString = "Title: Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon, Quantity: 2, Price: $18";
String resultRegexString = "Title\\: ([^,]+), Quantity\\: ([^,]+), Price\\: \\$([\\W\\w]+)";
```

or

```
String currentString = "Title:Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon,Quantity: 2, Price: $18";
String resultRegexString = "Title\\:([^,]+),Quantity\\: ([^,]+), Price\\: \\$([\\W\\w]+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply first split on `,` then split each key-value pair on `:`. The natural structure for this is a `Map`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String currentString = "Title:Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon,Quantity: 2, Price: $18";
    final Map<String, String> parsed = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (final String s : currentString.split("\\s*+,\\s*+")) {
        final String[] keyValuePair = s.split("\\s*+:\\s*+", 2);
        parsed.put(keyValuePair[0], keyValuePair[1]);
    }
}
```

I have added spaces around the split so that there is no need to `trim()`. The map now contains:

```
{Title=Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon, Quantity=2, Price=$18}
```

You can split out your desired output with:

```
    final Iterator<String> values = parsed.values().iterator();
    for (int i = 1; values.hasNext(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + values.next());
    }
```

Output:

```
1 - Great Value Naturally Hardwood Smoked Bacon
2 - 2
3 - $18
```